# When recaptcha gets rendered, a transparent container overlaps all the ui and spans all the viewport space

Tags: firebase, next.js

I'm working with next.js and firebase.

I'm doing authentication with google and with phone number.

The problem I have happens when authenticating with phone number, when the recaptcha is rendered, I can't click it and move forward to the next steps in the auth flow, because a transparent container also is rendered and overlaps completly ui.

I don't know why this happens, I followed every step of the google guide:
[Phone authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?hl=es-419)

My page component is the following...

In the page component I'm rendering a different form, one if it's time to write the verification code sent via SMS and another which is the first in being showed, to write and send the phone number.

```
import AppHead from '../../components/head'
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next"
import Select from '../../components/select'
import Nav from '../../components/nav'
import PhoneNumberInput from '../../components/phone-input'
import Dialog from '../../components/dialog'
import Footer from '../../components/footer'
import { isPossiblePhoneNumber } from 'react-phone-number-input'

export default function Home({ M, authService, libService }) {
    const verificationCodeInput = useRef(null)
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("")
    const [shouldVerify, setShouldVerify] = useState(false)
    const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false)
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(2)
    const [confirmationCode, setConfirmationCode] = useState('')
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation('common')
    let verificationValidClass = ""

    const onChangePhoneNumber = (value) => {
        setPhoneNumber(value)
    };

    const onClickLoginWithPhone = async (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault()
        try {
            if (isPossiblePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)) {
                const confirmationResult = await authService.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, window.recaptchaVerifier)
                window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult
                setShouldVerify(true)
            } else {
                setOpenDialog(true)
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    };

    const phoneNumberForm = (
        <form className="home__formLogin">
            <PhoneNumberInput onChangePhoneNumber={onChangePhoneNumber} phoneNumber={phoneNumber} labelText={t("forms.auth.phoneFieldLabel")} />
            <button data-target="phoneLoginModal" className="btn-large home__login-phone modal-trigger" onClick={onClickLoginWithPhone}>
                <span className="material-icons home__sendIcon" aria-hidden="true">
                    send
             </span>
                {t("forms.auth.sendPhone")}
            </button>
            <div id="recaptcha-container">

            </div>
        </form>
    )

    if (valid === 0) {
        verificationValidClass = "invalid"
    } else if (valid === 1) {
        verificationValidClass = "valid"
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
        const instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
        window.recaptchaVerifier = authService.getVerifier('recaptcha-container', (response) => setShouldVerify(true), () => console.log("captcha-expired"))
    }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <main className="main">
                <div className="main__layout home">
                    <Nav top={true} content={pickLanguage} contentLg={pickLanguageLG} />
                    <AppHead title={t("pages.login_phone.meta-title")} description={t("metaDescription")} />
                    <header className="home__header">
                        <h1>{shouldVerify ? t("pages.home.titleCode") : "LOGIN"}</h1>
                        <p>{t("pages.login_phone.subtitle_1")} <br /> {t("pages.login_phone.subtitle_2")}</p>
                    </header>

                    <section className="home__login-options">
                        <h1 className="home__formTitle">{shouldVerify ? t("pages.home.code") : t("pages.home.loginHeading")}</h1>
                        {shouldVerify ? verificationCodeForm : phoneNumberForm}
                        <Dialog open={openDialog} onConfirm={onClickConfirmDialog} heading={t("components.dialog.wrongPhoneNumber")} confirmText={t("components.dialog.wrongPhoneNumberConfirm")}>
                            {t("components.dialog.wrongPhoneNumberContent")}
                        </Dialog>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </main>
            <Footer />

        </>

    )
}
```

In the `useEffect` callback I create the verifier object and then in `onClickLoginWithPhone` I submit the phone number.

The function call `authService.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, window.recaptchaVerifier)` is implemented as shown below:

```
export default function AuthService(authProvider,firebase,firebaseApp) {
    return Object.freeze({
        signInWithPhoneNumber,
        getVerifier,
        getCredentials
    })


    function getVerifier(id,solvedCallback,expiredCallback){
        
        return new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container",{
                   'size': 'normal',
                   'callback': solvedCallback,
                   'expired-callback': expiredCallback
        });
    }

    //used when user signs in with phone number and need to introduce a verification code sended via SMS
    async function getCredentials(verificationId,verificationCode){
        const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId,verificationCode);
        const userCredential = await firebase.auth(firebaseApp).signInWithCredential(credential);
        return userCredential
    }

    async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, phoneVerifier) {
        const confirmationResult = await firebase.auth(firebaseApp).signInWithPhoneNumber(`${phoneNumber}`, phoneVerifier)
        return confirmationResult
    }


}
```

The container that is displayed is the following:

The part highlighted in blue is the full element which appears when I submit the phone number, and the part highlighted in red is the div which spans all the viewport and dont let me click the captcha widget

I really don't know why this thing is displayed, I'm not manipulating the DOM when submit the phone number, so I guess this problem is related to using next with firebase or with firebase itself.

[image]

**Note:** `t("<json-object-field>")`, `t` is just a function which reads an specific json file (a different one depending on the language the page is being showed) which contains all the strings translated to an specific language and this function returns a translated string individually.

The captcha widget is rendered but the container overlaps it, the container is transparent.

[image]

Comment: `Can you present a screenshot?`

Comment: I've added an screenshot of the ui and of the dom when the container I talking about gets rendered. let me know if you need more information.